# Construct new django model object without loading all related models into memory

Tags: python, django

I want to be able to construct a new django object by specifying the primary keys of the related objects, rather than loading those related objects into memory to pass to the model's constructor.  Is this possible?  Is there a model creation factory or something similar that constructs the underlying SQL without actually loading the objects into memory?

Example:

```
class ObjectChildEntity(models.Model):
    myobject = models.ForeignKey(MyObject)
    some_data = models.TextField(null=False,blank=False)
    related_stuff = models.ForeignKey(StuffModel)
```

I want to be able to do something like this:

```
new_child_entity= django.db.models.new(ObjectChildEntity, myobject__id = 123, some_data='foo', related_stuff__id = 456)
```

This of course isn't a real method, but what I want to accomplish is avoiding the loading of `MyObject` instance with id 123 into memory and the loading of `StuffModel` instance with id 456 into memory just for the purpose of passing these two objects into the `ObjectChildEntity` constructor.

Is there anything similar that exists for Django object creation without having to roll my own custom SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work fine using the usual model class constructor and the `_id` name rather than an `__id` chained relationship as in your example code for the foreign key id:

```
new_child_entity = ObjectChildEntity(myobject_id=123, some_data='foo', related_stuff_id=456)
new_child_entity.save()
```

Or, if you've overridden the [`db_column`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/fields/#database-representation) field in the model field declaration, that name instead of `myobject_id`.

Comment: This works if db_column is 'id', but doesn't work if the db_column field itself has an underscore in it (e.g. 'foo_id').

Comment: If the FK field is itself named `foo_id` I'd have to check on exactly how Django will construct the implied actual `db_column` field - possibly `foo_id_id`. But I cannot think of a real world situation in which you'd want to do that. With a legacy database, leave the `foo_id` version as the `db_column` value and name the field something sensible. With a non-legacy database, name the field something sensible and let Django pick the `db_column`. The point is to have the name for the FK field not match the `db_column`, then set the `db_column` to the integer FK rather than Python object.